"Implicit arguments declaration relies on type, discarding", meaning in Coq
I am proving some basic things in Coq as an exercise.
Here is the hypothetical syllogism, corresponding to combining functions in reverse order.
Definition syl : (forall x y z, (x -> y) -> (y -> z) -> (x -> z)) :=
  fun {A B C} (f : A -> B) (g : B -> C) x => g (f x).

I get the following warning output:
sh:2 $ coqc example.v
File "./example.v", line 2, characters 7-8:
Warning: Implicit arguments declaration relies on type. Discarding
incompatible declaration in term. [implicits-in-term,implicits,default]
File "./example.v", line 2, characters 9-10:
Warning: Implicit arguments declaration relies on type. Discarding
incompatible declaration in term. [implicits-in-term,implicits,default]
File "./example.v", line 2, characters 11-12:
Warning: Implicit arguments declaration relies on type. Discarding
incompatible declaration in term. [implicits-in-term,implicits,default]

This is the same warning three times, I imagine once each for A, B, and C.
What does this warning mean?

I'm not sure, but I guess this means that whether an argument of syl is implicit or not just depends on its type (in which no arguments are implicit), and not on its value, so even though you have declared A, B and C as implicit, that information is discarded in favor of the type declaration of syl.

The warnings are saying that you already indicated that x y z are not implicit arguments, and the subsequent annotation {A B C} contradicts that.
If you want implicit arguments, you should put them on the left of :=
Definition syl : forall {x y z}, (x -> y) -> (y -> z) -> (x -> z) :=
  fun A B C (f : A -> B) (g : B -> C) x => g (f x).

or
Definition syl {A B C} : (A -> B) -> (B -> C) -> (A -> C) :=
  fun (f : A -> B) (g : B -> C) x => g (f x).

